# Convert text file to plink PED and MAP format

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have the following data (small part of it) named "short2_pre_snp_tumor.txt"

```
rs987435        C       G       1       1       1       0       2
rs345783        C       G       0       0       1       0       0
rs955894        G       T       1       1       2       2       1
rs6088791       A       G       1       2       0       0       1
rs11180435      C       T       1       0       1       1       1
rs17571465      A       T       1       2       2       2       2
rs17011450      C       T       2       2       2       2       2
rs6919430       A       C       2       1       2       2       2
rs2342723       C       T       0       2       0       0       0
rs11992567      C       T       2       2       2       2       2
```

and I need to get the [PED and MAP](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/data.shtml#ped) file using Python, as R is really slow in case of large dataset.

I have the following code in R:

```
 tm <- proc.time()
    d<-read.table("short2_pre_snp_tumor.txt")
    n<-nrow(d)  #237196
    nrs<-ncol(d)-3 #1116
    dd<- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow= ncol(d)-3, ncol=2*nrow(d)), stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

    for (j in 1:nrs) {
    for (i in 1:n)  { 
    if (d[i, j+3]==0) {
    dd[j, 2*i-1]<-as.character(d[i,2])
    dd[j, 2*i]<-as.character(d[i,2])
    } else if (d[i, j+3]==1) {
    dd[j, 2*i-1]<-as.character(d[i,2])
    dd[j, 2*i]<-as.character(d[i,3])
    } else if (d[i, j+3]==2) {
    dd[j, 2*i-1]<-as.character(d[i,3])
    dd[j, 2*i]<-as.character(d[i,3])
    }
    }
    }


 ped6front<-data.frame(FID = 1: nrow(dd), IID= 1: nrow(dd), PID=0, MID=0, SEX= sample(1:2, nrow(dd), replace=T), PHENOTYPE=2)
    BRCA_tumorfromR.ped <- cbind(ped6front,dd)
   write.table(BRCA_tumorfromR.ped, “BRCA_tumor.ped”, append=FALSE, quote=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

    proc.time() #ptm
```

Comment: plink is not what you think. Edited out. And could you be more specific? because we don't know your trade. What do you want to extract (columns? rows?) and show us your code, promise I won't downvote even if it is bad :)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre I want to perform an Association analysis using Plink.. so I have the code in R to get the PED and the MAP file but it takes long time to get the results

Comment: still, I don't know what a PED or a MAP file. Can you transcribe it in simple column name, etc... generic language not bioinformatics lingo.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I added links to plink's PED MAP formats.

Comment: R would be pretty quick, too, if we manage to vectorise the solution. With your current script, we are looping through every row, this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is using R:

```r
# raw data
myRaw <- read.table(text = "
rs987435        C       G       1       1       1       0       2
rs345783        C       G       0       0       1       0       0
rs955894        G       T       1       1       2       2       1
rs6088791       A       G       1       2       0       0       1
rs11180435      C       T       1       0       1       1       1
rs17571465      A       T       1       2       2       2       2
rs17011450      C       T       2       2       2       2       2
rs6919430       A       C       2       1       2       2       2
rs2342723       C       T       0       2       0       0       0
rs11992567      C       T       2       2       2       2       2")

nIndividuals <- ncol(myRaw) - 3
nSNPs <- nrow(myRaw)

# make map, easy
MAP <- data.frame(
  CHR = 1,
  SNP = myRaw$V1,
  CM = 0,
  BP = seq(nSNPs))

# get first 6 columns of PED, easy
PED6 <- data.frame(
  FID = seq(nIndividuals),
  IID = seq(nIndividuals),
  FatherID = 0,
  MotherID = 0,
  Sex = 1,
  Phenotype = 1)

# convert 0,1,2 to genotypes, a bit tricky
# make helper dataframe for matching alleles
myAlleles <- data.frame(
  AA = paste(myRaw$V2, myRaw$V2),
  AB = paste(myRaw$V2, myRaw$V3),
  BB = paste(myRaw$V3, myRaw$V3))

# make index to match with alleles
PEDsnps <- myRaw[, 4:ncol(myRaw)] + 1

# convert
PEDsnpsAB <- 
  sapply(seq(nSNPs), function(snp)
    sapply(PEDsnps[snp, ], function(ind) myAlleles[snp, ind]))

# column bind first 6 cols with genotypes
PED <- cbind(PED6, PEDsnpsAB)

#output PED and MAP
write.table(PED, "gwas.ped", quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")
write.table(MAP, "gwas.map", quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")

# test plink
# plink --file gwas
# PLINK v1.90b3c 64-bit (2 Feb 2015)         https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2
# (C) 2005-2015 Shaun Purcell, Christopher Chang   GNU General Public License v3
# Logging to plink.log.
# 258273 MB RAM detected; reserving 129136 MB for main workspace.
# .ped scan complete (for binary autoconversion).
# Performing single-pass .bed write (10 variants, 5 people).
# --file: plink.bed + plink.bim + plink.fam written.
```

Comment: I have a question why phenotype=1 ?

Comment: @MarwahSoliman It can be any phenotype you have, I used dummy 1, meaning everyone is control. We can also skip this column, but then we need to use "--no-pheno" flag.

Comment: actually this data is for people who has tumor then the phenotype=2 , right?

Comment: if I need to generalize the code for the whole data set not just the 10 rows but they have the same number of columns what should be modified because I got NA beyond that.

Comment: @MarwahSoliman In my code the number of columns and rows are calculated from the input data. If your "real" data is the same as the example you provided, then above code should work fine. Please ensure the genotypes are always 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: I got the following output for the .ped file  > PED
  { FID IID FatherID MotherID Sex Phenotype   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
V4   1   1        0        0   1         1 C G C C G T A G C T A T T T C C C C T T
V5   2   2        0        0   1         1 C G C C G T G G C C T T T T A C T T T T
V6   3   3        0        0   1         1 C G C G T T A A C T T T T T C C C C T T
V7   4   4        0        0   1         1 C C C C T T A A C T T T T T C C C C T T
V8   5   5        0        0   1         1 G G C C G T A G C T T T T T C C C C T T}

Comment: it give me warnings when I run the PEDsnps <- myRaw[, 4:ncol(myRaw)] + 1, it says  In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: I used the following, PEDsnps <- as.numeric(as.character( myRaw[ , 4:ncol(myRaw)]))+1, is this correct

Comment: I don't know how to fix the error I tried so many things it doesn't work, could you help please??

Comment: @MarwahSoliman solution works for the data you provided, I can't help, if you don't supply representative data.

Comment: the data is  905460 x 1119, so as in the example I provided it has 1119 columns instead of 8 columns , the 1st to 3rd columns are the same and starting from the 4th column it is just 0,1 or 2

Comment: @MarwahSoliman by representative, I meant, I need to have the data that would fail my solution. If I cannot reproduce the problem I cannot help.

Comment: I found the solution, Thank you, again I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Please share your solution.

Comment: sorry it took me time to answer, the problem was that there was a character "-" that made 0,1,2 be read as a factor so I reclined the data and it works but it took long time , R is not good for huge data set